# Use a flask session inside a python thread

Tags: python, session, flask

How can I update a flask session inside a python thread? The below code is throwing this error:

*** RuntimeError: working outside of request context

```
from flask import session
def test(ses):
    ses['test'] = "test"

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def mytest():
    t = threading.Thread(target=test, args=(session, ))
    t.start()
```

Comment: See [Making an asynchronous task in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55440793/4934640) for an alternative example.

Answer (score 4):

When you execute `t.start()`, you are creating an independent thread of execution which is *not synchronized with the execution of the main thread in any way.*

The Flask [`session` object](//flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.session) is **only defined in the [context of a particular HTTP request](//flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/reqcontext/)**.

What does the variable `session` **mean** in the second thread (`t`)?

When `t` executes, there is no guarantee that the user request from the main thread still exists or is in a modifiable state. Perhaps the HTTP request has already been fully handled in the main thread.

Flask detects that you are trying to manipulate an object that is dependent on a particular context, and that your code is not running in that context. So it raises an exception.

There are a variety of approaches to synchronizing output from multiple threads into a single request context but... **what are you actually trying to do here?**

Comment: In my case, I wanted to run the function "test" as a thread  because it is doing a lot of things and will take a long time to execute and I don't want to wait for it to finish, so I just run the thread that will be updating the status of the processes running in a session variable, and I ll be checking (using ajax calls) the status of these processes from the session variable. In other words the idea is to do the first ajax call just run the processes without waiting for a response and have the next ajax calls check on the status.

Comment: This is certainly possible, but you need a mechanism to synchronize the background task with the main thread. I suggest you take a look at the [background task with threads example](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xi-email-support) from Miguel Grinberg's flask tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

None of the documentation I've seen really elaborates why this isn't possible in this framework - it's as if they have never heard of the use case.

In a nutshell, the built in session uses the user's browser (the cookie) as storage for the session - this is not what I understand sessions to be, and oh boy the security issues - don't store any secrets in there - the session is basically JSON encoded, compressed then set as a cookie - at least it's signed, I guess.

Flask-Session mitigates the security issues by behaving more like sessions do in other frameworks - the cookie is just an opaque identifier meaningful only in the back end - but the value changes every time the session changes, requiring the cookie be sent to the browser again - a background thread won't have access to the request when it's been completed a long time ago, so all you have is a one way transfer of data - out of the session and into your background task.

Might I suggest the baggage claim pattern?  Your initial request handling function designates some key in some shared storage - a file on disk, a row in a database identified by some key, an object key in an in memory cache - whatever - and puts that in the session, then passes the session to your background process which can inspect the session for the location to place the results.  Your subsequent request handling functions can then check this location for the results.