# How to send asynchronous request using flask to an endpoint with small timeout session?

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask

I am new to backend development using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and I am getting stuck on a confusing problem.  I am trying to send data to an endpoint whose Timeout session is 3000 ms. My code for the server is as follows.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from gitStat import getGitStat

import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def handle_data():
    params = request.args["text"].split(" ")

    user_repo_path = "https://api.github.com/users/{}/repos".format(params[0])
    first_response = requests.get(
        user_repo_path, auth=(
            'Your Github Username', 'Your Github Password'))

    repo_commits_path = "https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/commits".format(params[
                                                                            0], params[1])
    second_response = requests.get(
        repo_commits_path, auth=(
            'Your Github Username', 'Your Github Password'))

    if(first_response.status_code == 200 and params[2] < params[3] and second_response.status_code == 200):

        values = getGitStat(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3])

        response_url = request.args["response_url"]

        payload = {
            "response_type": "in_channel",
            "text": "Github Repo Commits Status",
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "text": values
                }
                    ]
            }

        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla /5.0 (Compatible MSIE 9.0;Windows NT 6.1;WOW64; Trident/5.0)'}

        response = requests.post(response_url, json = test, headers = headers)

    else:

        return "Please enter correct details. Check if the username or reponame exists, and/or Starting date < End date. \
                Also, date format should be MM-DD"
```

My server code takes arguments from the request it receives and from that request's JSON object, it extracts parameters for the code. This code executes *getGitStats* function and sends the JSON payload as defined in the server code to the endpoint it received the request from.

My problem is that I need to send a text confirmation to the endpoint that I have received the request and data will be coming soon. The problem here is that the function, *getGitStats* take more than a minute to fetch and parse data from Github API.

I searched the internet and found that I need to make this call asynchronous and I can do that using queues. I tried to understand the application using **RQ** and **RabbitMQ** but I neither understood nor I was able to convert my code to an asynchronous format. Can somebody give me pointers or any idea on how can I achieve this?

Thank you.

------------Update------------

Threading was able to solve this problem. Create another thread and call the function in that thread.

Comment: See [Making an asynchronous task in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55440793/4934640) for an alternative example.

Comment: @user Thanks for sharing this link! At that time my searching skills weren't that good I guess.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are trying to have a async task in request, you have to decide whether you want the result/progress or not.

1. You don't care about the result of the task or if there where any errors while processing the task. You can just process this in a Thread and forget about the result.
2. If you just want to know about success/fail for the task. You can store the state of the task in Database and query it when needed.
3. If you want progress of the tasks like (20% done ... 40% done). You have to use something more sophisticated like *celery*, *rabbitMQ*.

For you i think option #2 fits better. You can create a simple table GitTasks.

```
  GitTasks
  ------------------------
  Id(PK) | Status   | Result
  ------------------------ 
   1     |Processing| -
   2     | Done     | <your result>
   3     | Error    | <error details>
```

You have to create a simple Threaded object in python to processing.

```
 import threading  
 class AsyncGitTask(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, task_id, params):
        self.task_id = task_id
        self.params = params
    def run():
        ## Do processing
        ## store the result in table for id = self.task_id
```

You have to create another endpoint to query the status of you task.

```
  @app.route('/TaskStatus/<int:task_id>')
  def task_status(task_id):
      ## query GitTask table and accordingly return data
```

Now that we have build all the components we have to put them together in your main request.

```
  from Flask import url_for
  @app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
  def handle_data():
    .....
    ## create a new row in GitTasks table, and use its PK(id) as task_id
    task_id = create_new_task_row()
    async_task = AsyncGitTask(task_id=task_id, params=params)
    async_task.start()

    task_status_url = url_for('task_status', task_id=task_id)
    ## This is request you can  return text saying 
    ## that "Your task is being processed. To see the progress 
    ## go to <task_status_url>"
```

Comment: I used the first result as I was sure that my code will run. Threading solved it.

Comment: I tried this solution, but Im trying to upload a file async to s3, when I am running the thread with the uploader I get this error: RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

Comment: Small improvement: use process instead of threads. Much better handling:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html