# Flask - notify sending service data was received, then process

Tags: python, http, flask

I have two minimal web microservices in Flask. One (call it **X**) receives a POST request from an external service. **X** then does some math and sends a POST to another service, **Y**. Currently, **X** waits for **Y** to finish its processing before **X** sends a result back to the initial external service. This whole pipeline takes 6-7 seconds on average, which is undesirable from a performance perspective.

What is the best-practice way of performing a fire-and-forget POST from **X** --> **Y** in Flask (if this is even a Flask-specific question; I'd rather not invoke another framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement clearly hints, using an asynchronous task queue. If your application is anything more than a *small* scale web API, I think using/implementing specialized tools for message queues would yield better results than any kind of *hacks* in Flask.

A general workflow would then become as follows, external service sends POST request to X. X sends a message to Y (and forgets about it) and returns the response straight away to external service. Now it is the task of message queue to ensure the message is received by Y and Y handles it as desired.

If this workflow suits you, you can look into [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), both are fairly easy to set up. I have personally used RabbitMq with Flask and is quite satisfied with the result. Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31867108/5695235) answer for a bit of overview of using celery with Flask.