# Launching a non-blocking async function call via HTTP requests to a route in Python 3.6 Flask app

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, flask, async-await, python-asyncio

I am currently writing a small flask-based micro-service which launches other python scripts via calls to a CLI using python's `subprocess` module. My ultimate goal is make a non-blocking async function call triggered by http requests to a route in the service and have the service return `200` response from the route while the async function runs in the background.

I have been perusing the docs (I am using Python 3.6.3 for this service) cannot work out how to achieve this. Here is a small example of how my code is structured:

```
@app.route('/execute_job')
def execute_job():
    params = ...
    run_async_job(params)
    return 'Launched async job according to params, it is now running.'

async def run_async_job(params):
    command = 'run_python_cli_scripts args'
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command)
    # change some envs, do some file io, yada yada yada
    ...
    while True:
        if proc.poll() is not None: # the cli script is finished
            return notify_external_api_job_complete()
```

I know that simply calling `run_async_job(params)` does not actually begin its execution, but instead returns an `awaitable` or `Task` which must been thrown in an `event_loop`. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to run this task in an `event_loop` such that the `return` in `execute_ job` is reached before it completes. Is this sort of thing possible? This is my first foray into async python, and I am looking for behaviour similar to what you would see in async javascript. Is trying to use `async def` for the function I want to be non-blocking the wrong approach or is there a way to launch the tasks in an `event_loop` in a non-blocking fashion so that the aforementioned `return 'Launched async job according to params, it is now running.'` can be reached and the function completed before `run_async_job(params)` completes?

Thanks in advance for your time and wisdom.

Comment: Flask, by design, is not asynchronous.  You can use other tools to make this work though.  One idea is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31867108/429982)

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw to posterity: I opted for using a child process launched via the `subprocess` module. This was achievable by converting the library file I imported my `async def`'d function from into a script which uses command line arguments parsed from the `argparse` module. My route now looks like

```
@app.route('/execute_job')
def execute_job():
    params = ...
    command = ('python', params)
    subprocess.Popen(command)
    return 'Launched async job according to params, it is now running.'
```

edit: formatting