# Making asynchronous HTTP requests from a flask service

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, gunicorn

I have a couple different needs for asynchrony in my Python 3.6 Flask RESTful web service running under Gunicorn.

1) I'd like for one of my service's routes to be able to send an HTTP request to another HTTP service and, without waiting for the response, send a response back to the client that called my service.

Some example code:

```
@route
def fire_and_forget():
    # Send request to other server without waiting 
    # for it to send a response.
    # Return my own response.
```

2) I'd like for another one of my service's routes to be able to send 2 or more asynchronous HTTP requests to other HTTP services and wait for them all to reply before my service sends a response.

Some example code:

```
@route
def combine_results():
    # Send request to service A
    # Send request to service B
    # Wait for both to return.
    # Do something with both responses
    # Return my own response.
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am trying to avoid the additional complexity of using a queue (e.g. celery).

Answer (score 0):

You can use eventlets for the the second use case.  It's pretty easy to do:

```
import eventlet

providers = [EventfulPump(), MeetupPump()]
try:
    pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
    pile = eventlet.GreenPile(pool)
    for each in providers:
        pile.spawn(each.get, [], 5, loc)  # call the interface method
except (PumpFailure, PumpOverride):
    return abort(503)
results = []
for res in pile:
    results += res
```

You can wrap each of your api endpoints in a class that implements a "common interface" (in the above it is the get method) and you can make the calls in parallel.  I just place them all in a list.

Your other use case is harder to accomplish in straight python.  At least a few years ago you would be forced to introduce some sort of worker process like celery to get something like that done.  This question seems to cover all the issues:

[Making an asynchronous task in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866796/making-an-asynchronous-task-in-flask)

Perhaps things have changed in flask land?