# Flask return response but keep processing?

Tags: python, flask

I'm not sure if I worded the question correctly, but for example I want to return the response without returning the function.

My context here is, the user asks for a large excel file to be generate, so a link will be returned to him, and when the excel is done an email will also be sent.

Pseudo example :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import send_file
from someXlsLib import createXls
from someIoLib import deleteFile
from someMailLib import sendMail
import uuid

app = Flask(__name__)   
host = 'https://myhost.com/myApi'

@app.route('/getXls')
def getXls:
    fileName = uuid.uuid4().hex + '.xls'
    downloadLink = host + '/tempfiles/' + fileName
    #Returning the downloadLink for the user to acces when xls file ready
    return downloadLink
    #But then this code is unreachable
    generateXls(fileName)

def generateXls(fileName, downloadLink)
    createXls('/tempfiles/' + fileName)
    sendMail(downloadLink)

@app.route('/tempfiles/<fileName>')
def getTempFile:
    #Same problem here, I need the user to finish the download before deleting the file
    return send_file('/tempfiles/' + fileName, attachment_filename=fileName)
    deleteFile('/tempfiles/' + fileName)
```

Comment: It seems that what you need is asynchronous actions. Take a look to `celery` or `asyncio`.

Comment: It seems that this post answers your problem using `celery` :
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866796/making-an-asynchronous-task-in-flask

Comment: If you want to return a response and then to do something simple, [Deferred Request Callbacks](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/deferredcallbacks/) may suffice.

Comment: @Fian but those will happen for every request, right?

Comment: You can tune it yourself: it's possible to call it after each request or call only on certain requests meeting certain conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other commenters are right that you need to use something to manage asynchronous actions. One of the most popular options, and one that comes with lots of tools for completing delayed, scheduled, and asynchronous actions is [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html). You can do what you want using celery with something like the following:

```
from celery import Celery

...

# This is for Redis on the local host. You can also use RabbitMQ or AWS SQS.
celery = Celery(app.name, broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')    
celery.conf.update(app.config)

...

# Create your Celery task
@celery.task(bind=True)
def generateXls(file_name, downloadLink):
    createXls('/tempfiles/' + fileName)
    sendMail(downloadLink)

@app.route('/getXls')
def getXls:
    fileName = uuid.uuid4().hex + '.xls'
    downloadLink = host + '/tempfiles/' + fileName
    # Asynchronously call your Celery task.
    generateXls.delay(file_name, downloadLink)
    return downloadLink
```

This will return the download link immediately while continuing with `generateXls` in its own thread.

Comment: This indeed worked, but unfortunately I just noticed my host (pythonanywhere) does not support this. Not sure if I need another host or another solution now.

Comment: If Redis is the issue, you can set up [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/getting-started/) without installing anything on your local host, or run Redis or RabbitMQ on a remote host.

Comment: @Mojimi Did you ever get this issue resolved?  I noticed you may not have seen (as I didn't tag you) my message about addressing the broker installation issue by using a remote broker. If this answer works, can you mark it answered?

Comment: Yes, well I knew about celery already, just wondered if there was something built in Flask to continue processing.