# Python Flask - Asyncio asynchronous Question

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading, aiohttp, python-asyncio

I have a web endpoint for users to upload file.
When the endpoint receives the request, I want to run a background job to process the file.

Since the job would take time to complete, I wish to return the job_id to the user to track the status of the request while the job is running in **background**.

I am wondering if asyncio would help in this case.

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def process_file(job_id, file_obj):
     <process the file and dump results in db>

@app.route('/file-upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    job_id = uuid()
    process_file(job_id, requests.files['file']) . # I want this call to be asyc without any await
    return jsonify('message' : 'Request received. Track the status using: " + `job_id`)
```

With the above code, process_file method is never called. Not able to understand why.

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it though, please help if I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

Flask doesn't support async calls yet.

To create and execute heavy tasks in background you can use https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/ Celery library.

You can use this for reference:
[Making an asynchronous task in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866796/making-an-asynchronous-task-in-flask)

Official documentation:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#installing-celery

Even though you wrote `@asyncio.coroutine()` around a function it is never `awaited` which tells a function to return result.

Asyncio is not good for such kind of tasks, because they are blocking I/O. It is usually used to make function calls and return results fast.

Answer (score 1):

As [@py_dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3652949/py-dude) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58996863/1305461), `Flask` does not support async calls. If you are looking for a library that functions and feels similar to `Flask` but is asynchronous, I recommend checking out [`Sanic`](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Here is some sample code:

```py
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

app = Sanic()

@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
    return json({"hello": "world"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Updating your database asynchronously shouldn't be an issue; refer to [here](https://github.com/timofurrer/awesome-asyncio#database-drivers) to find asyncio-supported database drivers. For processing your file, check out [`aiohttp`](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles). You can run your server extremely fast on a single thread without any hickup if you do so asynchronously.

Comment: `Sanic` will not process background tasks for you

Comment: @py_dude What? No, no -- `Sanic` just allows **any other** process to run asynchronously with the servers. If he is planning on just doing small processes to the file and updating a database `Sanic` would be a great tool to use.

Comment: that's the point, he's not going to just write to DB. he's going to compute something really heavy

Comment: I updated my answer for ya, and added `aiofiles`. Just giving options.

Comment: To clarify further, OP did not mention that he would be computing something heavy. Unsure why the lack of criticism with a downvote.