# Running a background task in flask once a certain url is called

Tags: python, azure, flask, web-applications

Once a url is called like:  `www.example.com/run_this_thing` I want a background task to initiate. Its like i want to run a script in background once a certain url is called. It takes around 10 minutes to complete. This url is called like once in 3-5 hours only

Snippet of what I am using:

```
@app.route('/run_this_thing')
def damn_man():
    myobject = myscript.MyClass(arguments)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=myobject.run)
    t1.start()
    return "<h1> IT IS RUNNING!!! </h1>"
```

Also, whats interesting is that, I deployed in azure server web app and it works like first few times. Then it does not. I am quite beginner at flask. **It works when I push through git once every few hours but thats not feasible at all.**

I also tried. It does not return anything but runs background task few times and after some hours of deployment in azure it returns server error!!!

```
@app.route('/this_should_really_run', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def damn_it():
    myobject = myscript.MyClass(arguments)
    return myobject.run()
```

For solution::

- It would be perfect if I can find solution to make run the script every few hours instead of need to
  go to the url to make the task run. *For this also i tried threading but no luck.*
- If not, it would be great if on visiting the site either the function would be called or anything just once the website is visited the script should run.

I have heard and saw something like celery but looks a lot of trouble like **broker url and backend url** [this_question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866796/making-an-asynchronous-task-in-flask) can it be used on azure?
It is deployed on azure as web app which uses linux and python3.8 as runtime.

Comment: have you thought about putting your code into a timer-triggered (durable) Azure Function?

Comment: how to integrate in flask application. I saw some docs but I dont know how. It shows some events and activity but i dont know how to create one. How do i use that in my case?

`yield context.call_activity("DoCleanup")` 
What is doCleanup here? cant I pass function as the task to do and simply put it on flask?

Comment: what do you need flask for if you just want to run some python script every couple of hours? (thats my understanding of what you are trying here?!)

Comment: I have a website running as well that's running perfectly. Leave that. If I wanted to run python script every few hours on azure (assume there is no website just python script to run on azure). How do i do it? how do i  `call_activity` like shown above? Any resources or anything that would help?

Comment: How do you deploy the flask to Azure web app and how do you run the flask as a background task?