# Is there a way to make flask asynchronous

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Is there a way to make flask asynchronous? For example I want flask to pause for one second for a user and then display some text. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is best implemented on the client side using Javascript. Flask is a server side framework.

Comment: Please explain why you want this. It may help to understand which solution makes sense for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask is based WSGI which is an API standard for connecting Python Web frameworks to Web servers.
And WSGI is a synchronous and blocking API.

If you are using flask render_template, like this :

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET'])
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('hello.html', name=name)
```

You can add a time.sleep() to make if wait before rendering the template.
***But this is not a good practice***

```
import time

@app.route('/home', methods=['GET'])
def hello(name=None):
    time.sleep(30) #wait 30seconds
    return render_template('hello.html', name=name)
```

But if you want to use it with a frontend in javascript, you should handle it on the client side.

And if you want to know about async tasks on flask you can take a look on [Celery](https://pypi.org/project/celery/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866796/making-an-asynchronous-task-in-flask).