# How to run continuous I/O task in parallel to flask.run() asynchronously?

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'd like to implement a flask based web server which continuously reads data (e.g. from a keyboard, but could be any "outside world" device) and replies to GET requests based on that data.

An easy to imagine use case would be a web service telling whether or not a certain key on the keyboard is currently pressed.

A naive approach would be to just start a thread, which continuously reads keyboard events and modifies a data structure based on those events and in parallel run a flask app using the data structure.

I'm now wondering if it's possible to run those tasks in parallel using `asyncio` instead of threads (for safety reasons and out of curiosity)

I found lots of questions and answers regarding `flask` and `async` requests, but those (I think) handle the case when you have multiple requests in parallel you want to reply to asynchronously. (e.g. this one: [Making an asynchronous task in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866796/making-an-asynchronous-task-in-flask#31867108)). In contrast I don't need asynchronously handled requests but a continuously running task in parallel to the web server.

An approach I would think of could look like this:

```
import asyncio
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/")

class Keyboard:
    def was_pressed(self, key):
        if key in self.pressed:
            self.pressed.remove(a)
            return True
        return False
    async def handle_event(self, key):
        self.pressed.add(key)

keyboard = Keyboard()

@app.route("/waspressed/<path:key>")
def waspressed(key):
    return Response(str(keyboard.was_pressed(key)))

async def continuously_update_keyboard_state():
    while True:
        keyboard.handle_event(await keyboard_event())

async def main():
  await asyncio.gather(
    continuously_update_keyboard_state(), 
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="9000"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

but `flask.Flask.run()` is not implemented using `async`. So that approach is not possible, correct? Can I somehow wrap it? Am I on a completely wrong track here?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Quart](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart) instead of Flask for an asynchronous web service. It has the exact same API as Flask but is built with the intention of being async.

```
import asyncio
from quart import Quart, Response

app = Quart(__name__, static_url_path="/")
```