Concatenate multiple API calls
In my code, I have a list of CU (IDs) that I use in a URL for an API call:
for chunk in cu_chunks:
    cu_string = ','.join(chunk)
    url = f'{base_url}?CU={cu_string}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(f'Status code for request with {len(chunk)} CUs: {response.status_code}')

That calls this:
@app.route('/CU', methods=['GET'])
def CU():
    cu_string = request.args.get('CU', type=str)
    
    cu_list = cu_string.split(',') 
    jm.create_job_CU(cu_list)
    ret = jsonify([job.result for job in jm.completed_jobs])
    jm.completed_jobs = []
    return ret

And then in the create job I have all the stuff.
If I have too many CUs, the URL is too long and it leads to an error, hence the decision to divide the CUs in chunks and make multiple API calls, as in the code above.
The API calls some functions that make some predictions by using some machine learning algorithms and then it pushes the results to the database.
The problem is that the calls make the code running quite slow, so I need a solution to keep the multiple calls but, instead of doing everything, I'd like the create job to only store all the CUs from the call, and then when they're over, to start all the functions only once with all the CUs.
Is it possible to do something like this?

my intuition tell me you want to leverage a queue.

Asynchronous task queues will let your API service accept these calls and then schedule tasks for a different service to execute. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866796/making-an-asynchronous-task-in-flask
