# Dash getting session object variables throws the dreaded Runtime Error

Tags: python, flask, session, plotly-dash

I have searched far and wide, including SO, for a possible suggestion to this error.

Running a dash app on a server that needs to grab information from the session variable.

This is the beginning code of the dash app page that eventually errors out.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from numpy.lib.function_base import select
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash_core_components.RadioItems import RadioItems
import csv
import numpy as np
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
from datetime import datetime
import time
from datetime import date
now = pd.to_datetime('now')
#Dash Stuff
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_table

import pyodbc
from flask import request, session
from app import app, server

connectionStr = server.config.get('DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING', None)
conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionStr)
#print(session.get('udata'))
```

When I run this code via my index.py file, I get the following error.

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

And, so, I have read the documentation, as best I can determine which of the Flask documentation this error refers.  The request and context and application context documentation. You will notice, I am not using a request call at all, which makes the error confusing.

Anyone with dash apps that have to inherit session variables to show the appropriate user data would be a big help here.

Comment: `session` also falls under the request context, so that's the reason for the error. You can use `session` inside a route. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do exactly. Depending on what you're trying to do there might be better ways to go about it.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31348400/9098350).

Comment: Just trying to grab session data to display data in callbacks only associated with that logged in user.

Comment: The session object I mean. I’m assuming it’s a dictionary and I’m just trying to get values from it. What would it look like to grab that information from within a request context?  I’ve read up on that but don’t understand it.